# Why is my twitter oauth access token invalid / expired

Tags: php, twitter, token, twitter-oauth

I am using Twitter to log users into to a website, which seems to be working up until I attempt to obtain a valid Access Token.

```
require("twitteroauth.php");
require 'twconfig.php';
session_start();

$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET);
$request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('http://****/tw_response.php');

$oauth_token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $oauth_token;

$oauth_token_secret = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $oauth_token_secret;

if ($twitteroauth->http_code == 200) {
    url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);
    header('Location: '.$url);
} else {
    die('Something wrong happened.');
}
```

This seems to be working correctly, redirecting me to twitter to sign in and confirm access, after which it returns me to tw_response.php (my Callback url), with the following variables in the url:

```
http://example.com/login.php?oauth_token=sO3X...yj0k&oauth_verifier=Ip6T...gALQ
```

In tw_response.php I then try to get the Access Token, but it reports as invalid.  I tried using `var_dump` to view the content of the access token as follows:

```
require("twitteroauth.php");
require 'twconfig.php';
session_start();

$oauth_verifier = $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];
$oauth_token = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
$oauth_token_secret = $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];

$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);

$access_token = $twitteroauth->getAccessToken($data['oauth_verifier']);
var_dump($access_token);
```

The result of the `var_dump` ends in "invalid / expired Token":

```
array(8) {
    ["oauth_url"] => string(104) ""1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/oauth/access_token?oauth_consumer_key=ceE...9Dg"
    ["oauth_nonce"]=> string(32) "c52...d07"
    ["oauth_signature"]=> string(28) "ry7...Fcc="
    ["oauth_signature_method"]=> string(9) "HMAC-SHA1"
    ["oauth_timestamp"]=> string(10) "1359031586"
    ["oauth_token"]=> string(40) "sO3...j0k"
    ["oauth_verifier"]=> string(43) "Ip6...ALQ"
    ["oauth_version"]=> string(63) "1.0 Invalid / expired Token "
}
```

Comment: This is using Abraham Williams' library? It seems that `getAccessToken(code)` only works when the page you call gives the user a code to type in after allowing access. I think you need to use both pieces of information when you use the callback-url.

Comment: If you are using your valid callback URL, you dont need to verify the `oauth_verifier` with your credentials. checking this out anyway.

Comment: Is your server clock running correctly?

Comment: I think this link can help you out http://www.phpgang.com/twitter-oauth-in-php_175.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$access_token = $twitteroauth->getAccessToken($data['oauth_verifier']);
var_dump($access_token);
```

Where did `$data` magically come from? You have the variable `$oauth_verifier`, but keep in mind you don't need this if this is your registered callback URL.

Since you used an invalid variable inside `getAccessToken`, it will return an invalid value back.

The correct way to use TwitterOAuth:

```
if (!isset($_GET["oauth_token"])) {
    // set these values in a config file somewhere.
    $twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

    // append a ?. This is your callback URL if you specify something.
    $credentials = $twitter->getRequestToken("http://example.com/test.php?");

    // try and be a bit more elegant with the URL... This is a minimal example
    $url = $twitter->getAuthorizeUrl($credentials);
    echo $url;

    // these are temporary tokens that must be used to fetch the new,
    // permanent access tokens. store these in some way,
    // session is a decent choice.
    $_SESSION["token"] = $credentials["oauth_token"];
    $_SESSION["secret"] = $credentials["oauth_token_secret"];
} else {

    // use the user's previously stored temporary credentials here
    $twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                    $_SESSION["token"], $_SESSION["secret"]);

    // uses the oauth_token (from the request) already.
    // you store these credentials in your database (see below).
    $credentials = $twitter->getAccessToken($_GET["oauth_verifier"]);

    // just a printout of credentials. store these, don't display them.
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($credentials);
    // valid credentials, provided you give the app access to them.
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

I just use a single script for callbacks for ease of use; you can split the relevant sections into multiple scripts if you like (and you probably should).

Handily for your database, the credentials include the twitter user's username, too.
**Edit**: [Twitter is now allocating 64bit integers for user IDs](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/64-bit-twitter-user-idpocalypse). You should *store this as a string* to ensure that you don't end up with mangled user IDs and collisions if you can't handle 64bit integers in every part of your application.

```
array(4) {
  ["oauth_token"]=>
  string(50) "7041...wYupkS"
  ["oauth_token_secret"]=>
  string(42) "O9ENq...21B2fk"
  ["user_id"]=> // user ID. always the same, never changes (store this as ID)
  string(9) "..."
  ["screen_name"]=> // username. can change.
  string(11) "..."
}
```

So, if you want to log users in through twitter, without explicitly giving them a login to your site, you could use `$_SESSION` (I use databases for my logins, which is recommended if you want to save that state)
In the above script you would add this to the end of the `else` block:

```
$_SESSION["token"] = $credentials["oauth_token"];
$_SESSION["secret"] = $credentials["oauth_secret"];
$_SESSION["username"] = $credentials["screen_name"];
```

You can also get the user's screen name and more from [`GET account/verify_credentials`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/verify_credentials), if you want to give them a user page (if you use javascript, grab their userid through `id_str` here):

```
$user_array = $twitter->get("account/verify_credentials");
```

Comment: +1 nice solution Hiroto! But How can we get the user's email?

Comment: @Arash user emails are private; you should store the user's ID instead. Contacting a user with email notifications would require them to give you their email with their explicit consent (by entering it into a form)

Comment: @Amelia When I do a `var_dump($credentials)`, I get one more element in array: `["x_auth_expires"]=> string(1) "0" `. I think this is the reason its giving me 'invalid/expired token'. Can you tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Just used new API of twitter some methods will not work. It is working with New methods as below:
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $oauth_access_token_secret));
var_dump($access_token);
After Getting the Access token pass new token in twitter instance again on any new page.

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret,$oauth_access_token,$oauth_access_token_secret);
  $content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
  print_r($content ); die('eee');

Answer (score 1):

If your OAuth flow was working one day and failing the next, check your computer's **clock**.  I was running a Vagrant box that somehow had its time set to the day before, which caused the Twitter API to return {"code":89,"message":"Invalid or expired token."}.  This may also appear as 401 timestamp out of bounds.  You can use this command to update your clock in Ubuntu:

```
sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov
```

[Alternative method](https://askubuntu.com/a/683136) if `ntpdate` isn't available on your system:

```
sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

If one doesn't pay one will only be able to create the dev environment (sandbox).

As I have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459087/7109869):

> Counts is only available to paid premium accounts, and one needs to pay for premium access.
>
> [Use this link to Apply for access](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apply-for-access).