# R- Invalid or expired token

Tags: r, twitter, token, tweets

i am trying to extract tweets with #rstats by using this:

```
rt <- search_tweets(
"#rstats", n = 18000, include_rts = FALSE
)
```

But I am getting this error:
    Searching for tweets...
    This may take a few seconds...
    Warning: 89 - Invalid or expired token.
    Finished collecting tweets!
    Warning message:
    Invalid or expired token.

Anybody knows why this is happening? I tried regenerating the tokens but doesn't seem to work. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter API - Reasons for "invalid or expired token"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636701/twitter-api-reasons-for-invalid-or-expired-token)

Comment: @gyx-hh Tried looking at those solutions, but nothing worked. So would appreciate any help