# Invalid or expired token on Twurl

Tags: twitter, twurl

I've done some research and found a question that wants to understand the [reasons for “invalid or expired token”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17636701/5675325) but that doesn't solve my problem / doesn't provide one solution to this case using twurl.

Situation is that

1. Registered app and got the Consumer API token & access, Access token & access.
2. Authentication succeeded (using pin code)

   ```
   twurl authorize --consumer-key ************** --consumer-secret *****************
   ```
3. Now get error "Invalid or expired token" when running the following command

   ```
   $ twurl /1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline
   ```

> {"errors":[{"code":89,"message":"Invalid or expired token."}]}

How can this be fixed?

Comment: / I repeated regenerating keys & tokens

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Without paying, you will only be able to create the dev environment (sandbox), which is something you haven't considered.

As I have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459087/7109869):

> Counts is only available to paid premium accounts, and one needs to pay for premium access.
>
> [Use this link to Apply for access](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apply-for-access).