# Count number of Tweets from the past 30 days using Twurl

Tags: twitter, endpoint, twurl

To request tweets from the [Standard search API with a specific hashtag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60399529/5675325), I've done

```
twurl "/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#jesus"
```

Tht worked fine. Now wanting to use the [Premium search APIs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search) to count the tweets from the past 30 days with the hashtag jesus.

In it, there's a Counts endpoint, `/search/:label/counts`.

For the tweets from the past 30 days, that's the endpoint pattern, `/search/30day/:label/counts.json`.

I've created a [Search Tweets: 30-Days Sandbox](https://developer.twitter.com/en/account/environments) with name *stackoverflow* (that is the label).

Then, when running the following

```
twurl "/1.1/tweets/search/30day/stackoverflow/counts.json?query=#jesus"
```

I get

> {"error":{"message":"Unauthorized: Stream is not enabled for count
>   requests","sent":"2020-02-26T13:26:57+00:00","transactionId":"00f67ea10058270b"}}

From this, decided to go to the app keys and tokens and regenerated both Consumer API keys and Access token & access token secret.

After

```
twurl authorize --consumer-key ************** --consumer-secret *****************
```

and using the PIN code I get

> Authorization successful

If I do again

```
twurl "/1.1/tweets/search/30day/stackoverflow/counts.json?query=#jesus"
```

Then get

> {"error":{"message":"Invalid or expired token.","sent":"2020-02-26T13:39:44+00:00","transactionId":"00dea42000a8a098"}}

Regenerated again both Consumer API keys and Access token & access token secret but still no success.

How can I do it then?

Comment: Counts is not available in the sandbox, it is only available to paid premium accounts.

Comment: @AndyPiper That's not what the pricing page points to. From it one understands that using the Premium search we wouldn't need to pay if:
(1) Tweets from the past 30 days, up to 250 requests / month, 100 tweets / request (total of 250000 tweets), (2) Tweets since 2006, up to 50 requests / month, 100 tweets / request (total of 5000 tweets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counts is only available to paid premium accounts, and one needs to pay for premium access.

[Use this link to Apply for access](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apply-for-access).

Comment: with Paid premium accounts, how we can calculate counts using python?