401 Error: "Invalid or expired token" while retrieving user information with Twitter API
I am experiencing a problem with my Flask application when trying to retrieve user information from the Twitter API. I keep receiving a 401 error with the message:

Erreur lors de la récupération des informations de l'utilisateur: 401 - {"errors":[{"code":89,"message":"Invalid or expired token."}]}

I am using a Basic subscription for the Twitter API, not the free one.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
import os

# Configurations de l'application
API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
API_SECRET_KEY = 'YOUR_API_SECRET_KEY'
CALLBACK_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    # Clear old tokens
    session.pop('oauth_token', None)
    session.pop('oauth_token_secret', None)
    session.pop('access_token', None)
    session.pop('access_token_secret', None)

    oauth = OAuth1Session(API_KEY, client_secret=API_SECRET_KEY, callback_uri=CALLBACK_URL)
    request_token_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
    fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)

    # Store tokens in session
    session['oauth_token'] = fetch_response.get('oauth_token')
    session['oauth_token_secret'] = fetch_response.get('oauth_token_secret')

    authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize')
    return redirect(authorization_url)

@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    oauth = OAuth1Session(API_KEY, client_secret=API_SECRET_KEY,
                          resource_owner_key=session.get('oauth_token'),
                          resource_owner_secret=session.get('oauth_token_secret'))

    if not session.get('oauth_token') or not session.get('oauth_token_secret'):
        return "Authentication error. Please try again."

    oauth_response = oauth.parse_authorization_response(request.url)

    # Store access tokens
    session['access_token'] = oauth_response.get('oauth_token')
    session['access_token_secret'] = oauth_response.get('oauth_token_secret')

    return redirect(url_for('profile'))

@app.route('/profile')
def profile():
    oauth = OAuth1Session(API_KEY, client_secret=API_SECRET_KEY,
                          resource_owner_key=session['access_token'],
                          resource_owner_secret=session['access_token_secret'])

    user_info_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'
    response = oauth.get(user_info_url)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        return f"Error retrieving user information: {response.status_code} - {response.text}"

    user_info = response.json()
    return render_template('profile.html', user=user_info)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

What I've tried:

I made sure my API keys (API_KEY and API_SECRET_KEY) are correct.
I cleared the session before starting the authentication process to ensure no old tokens are causing issues.
I have checked that the application has the necessary permissions for accessing user information.
Additional Information:
I am using a Basic subscription for the Twitter API.
The error appears when I try to access the /profile route after logging in.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue? What could be causing the "Invalid or expired token" error, and how can I resolve it?

Did you use the tips in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17994472/740553 to confirm that X (as much as we want to keep calling it Twitter, when we're talking about the current API that's X API, not the Twitter API) considers your keys value by checking the https://developer.x.com/en/docs/x-api/v1/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials route with a direct call to that URL using curl or the like?
