# Cannot connect to Twitter API from Postman

Tags: json, twitter, http-headers, twitter-oauth, postman

I do not understand. I am doing everything I am supposed to.

I have created an app in Twitter, generate the OAuth info, and now I'm trying to make some requests from Postman. But I am getting this error every singe time:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 32,
      "message": "Could not authenticate you."
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried several different ways, for example using the Oauth feature in Postman - as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34937790/1675976), just using a plain `Authorization` header, etc. However nothing is working

Has anyone had a similar experience or know how to fix this?

[image: Twitter Postman API]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working with the following steps:

- I went to `https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/tools/signature-generator` where I typed in the query I wanted to make and then clicked `Get OAuth Signature`.

[image: Twitter OAuth]

- Then in Postman, copy in the URL you generated an `OAuth` token for, and then copy the entire Authorization Header you generated.
- In Postman, click Bulk Edit and paste in the authorization header you copied

[image: Postman bulk edit]

That's it.

Click Send

Comment: Can't find site shown in anwers screenshot. Just see twitter search panel, which redirects to simple site search

Comment: Well I shared the link at the top of tje answer. Doh