# Get Twitter Timeline (JSON) using Postman Client

Tags: json, twitter, postman

I want to get user Twitter timeline in JSON using Postman client [Please find the screenshot of my request here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0QE8.png)

I have already followed already answered questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171374/how-to-make-calls-to-twitter-api-using-postman-client), but I am not able to get the response from Twitter.

I am getting the response as

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 32,
            "message": "Could not authenticate you."
        }
    ]
}
```

Now either Twitter has banned request from other client or I am doing it wrong please help.

Comment: Have you tried adding the Auth token as a header? In the image it looks like you’re adding it to the request body.

Comment: @DannyDainton I am adding screen_name in the header. How to add Aith token in header ?

Comment: It should be set via the drop down menu on the left, in your image. Select the request header option and hit preview request.

Comment: Thank you @DannyDainton You can write this as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Auth token to be used in the `request header` rather than part of the `request body`.

This can be set via the drop down option in the Auth feature. Select the option to use it as a request header and then hit the `Preview Request` button. You should be able to see this token on the list of headers.

Comment: I wish I could, but my reputation is less than 15 so I cannot upvote. Can you please upvote my question so I will gain more reputation and then might be able to upvote